# Swift : How to open specific link in safari instead UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview

I'm new with the Swift programming language.
Here is my problem. I created a UIWebView. Now I want to open some link in the Safari browser instead in the WebView.
I searched on the Internet different solutions like:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
        return false
    }
    return true
```

I don't know how to implement this inside my code.
This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //webview.delegate = self;
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let webURL = URL(string: "http://www.collegiodeirettori.net/palio/")
    if(webURL != URL(string: "http://www.collegiodeirettori.net/palio/*")){
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webURL!)
        webview.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        webview.scrollView.bounces = false
    } else{
        //let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webURL!)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(webURL!)
        //webview.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        //webview.scrollView.bounces = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the webview begins to load, OS would automatically invoke the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` function. You only need to implement that same code in your View Controller.

Comment: So I just have to put the function webView into the ViewDidLoad?
Well,I did it before ask a question here but it doesn't work because when I click on a link it opens inside the webview.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Man -**

```
let pathURL = "http://www.collegiodeirettori.net/palio/"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: pathURL.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)!)
```

Comment: I don't want to open the "main" URL but just some links like Facebook and Twitter's link or other web page.. How can I do the control of this link?